# Top 10 friends on the basis of similarity in network graph

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, similarity

I have 1000 users, and the adjacency list of their network. I am using igraph  library.

I have created graph using:

```
graph.adjlist(adjlist, mode = c("out", "in", "all", "total"),duplicate = TRUE)
```

Then to find out similarity between each users:

```
similarity.jaccard(graph, vids, mode, loops)
```

Similarly I am using `invlogweighted, dice etc` to get the similarity. The problem is, I want `top 10 most close friends` (only based on network graph) for each user. But I am not getting proper weights i.e most of the users have same similarity with each other, though their number of connections are different.

I want different weights between each user, so that I can select the `top 10 based on weights`. Is there something that can help me to get `top 10 friends of a user`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want similarity only based on the network structure I suggest you use algorithm which are Global structure based like SIMRANK,P-RANK etc.These will give you a far better result than local structure based similarity measures such as jaccard and cosine.

This paper is a good resource to brush up on it.
[http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2780000/2776894/a15-chen.pdf?ip=1.186.134.39&id=2776894&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=045416EF4DDA69D9%2E517DE04875AE9835%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=820582987&CFTOKEN=27992587&**acm**=1508403880_47ba9366223f4aba0e4a217dee002e25](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/2780000/2776894/a15-chen.pdf?ip=1.186.134.39&id=2776894&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=045416EF4DDA69D9%2E517DE04875AE9835%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&CFID=820582987&CFTOKEN=27992587&__acm__=1508403880_47ba9366223f4aba0e4a217dee002e25)